# TensorFlow: the best way to convert a scalar to a 1-dimensional tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to convert tensorflow scalars into 1-dimensional tensors with 1 element. 
I wonder what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`tf.reshape`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape)

For example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.constant(2)
x_1d = tf.reshape(x, [1])
```